# What is BBT event?

Tags: code-geass, code-geass-akito-the-exiled

In Akito the Exiled episode 2, there is a female scientist talking with a person in a lab tank and she mentioned about "BBT event". It seems it was about the four 11s being synced in battle. But still, what does it mean?

Comment: Please check if my edit changes the meaning of your post. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The scientist says "BRS", not "BBT" (this is around 54:12 into the episode).

Odds are that the "BR" stand for "Brain Raid" (which is a thing that is mentioned earlier by the same person, around 46:37). [Japanese Wikipedia claims](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA%A1%E5%9B%BD%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AD%E3%83%88#.E4.B8.BB.E8.A6.81.E4.BA.BA.E7.89.A9) that the "S" stands for "System", though I don't know where it gets that from.

[The official website](http://www.geass.jp/akito/kmf_alexander.html) describes "Brain Raid mode" (ブレインレイド状態) as a feature of the Alexander (the mech that Akito pilots):

> ブレインレイドの状態に突入すると、頭部のマスクが展開する。
> ブレインレイドとは、アレクサンダのパイロットの精神が拡張する機能。
> 拡張された精神はType-02の各パイロットの精神を浸食、各機を子機として自在に操ることができる。
>
> When the Alexander enters Brain Raid mode, its face mask deploys. During a Brain Raid, the pilot's mind "extends", allowing it to subsume the minds of other Type-02 pilots, allowing their mechs to be controlled as extensions of the main unit.

Comment: is this related to geass, soldier psychology or technology in knightmares?

Comment: @Esq I guess a bit of geass and a bit of knightmare technology? But we don't have enough information yet to really know much; the series is only at the half-way point right now, after all.